# Linux Shell Script: backup and restore files while maintaining directory location

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, backup

I am looking to write a Linux shell script in order to perform a backup and restore of all of the source code in my project folder **(.c, .cpp, .java, etc)**

My script deletes all of these source code files and I want to be able to easily restore the files as well if need be.

Here is what I am doing now:

```
#copy the entire directory to a backup folder
cp -r $CLEANUP_PATH $BACKUP_PATH

#delete the project and copy from backup to restore source code
rm -rf $CLEANUP_PATH
cp -r $BACKUP_PATH $CLEANUP_PATH
```

The project is around 600MB, so it takes a long time when I perform these actions.

How would I be able to restore only the source code (rather than the entire directory) from a backup and ensure that each file is restored to the specific directories that each file belongs in?

Comment: Why don't you just use source control?

Comment: Does `cp -r` copy dot files? i.e. .exrc, etc?

Comment: @Carl - The intent here is to remove source code to protect intellectual property. The backup/restore functionality would mostly be for internal testing purposes. Correct me if I'm mistaken, but I believe that using source control would be a considerably slower approach for this.

Comment: @shellter - One of the things that I tried was: 

find $CLEANUP_PATH -iname "*.c" -exec cp {} {}.bkup \;

However, this does not maintain the directory that the files came from when I go to restore from the backup.

cp -r copies a directory recursively including every single file in the root directory and all subdirectories.

Comment: Why are you copying and then removing?  If the destination and the source are on the same physical device, using mv will be a *lot* faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `tar`: it remembers everything about the files, including paths, permissions, and dates. If you source code is inside a few directories, you can extract those directiories by name from the tar file.

Comment: What would the syntax look like if I want to locate and backup all .c files from /home/username/PROJECT_FOLDER for example?

Comment: `tar zcvf /tmp/mybackup.tar.gz /home/username/PROJECT_FOLDER/*.c`

Comment: Thanks, but this ended up being the syntax that I needed:

`tar -zcvf ${BACKUP_PATH}/c_backup.tar find ${CLEANUP_PATH} -name "*.c"`

How do I extract these files to restore them to the directories they came from without overwriting other existing files in those directories?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  

`tar -xzvf c_backup.tar -C ${CLEANUP_PATH}`

Answer (score 2):

Consider using version control.  It remembers everything about the files, including paths, permissions, dates, and previous revisions.  This will not only prevent disaster recovery, but it will make you a better developer (for any number of reasons).

```
git init .
git add `find . -type f | egrep '\.(cpp|c|java)$'`
git commit -m "initial version"
```

The of course assumes you have stuff in the directory you do not want committed/saved.  If you want to save everything (no binaries/library/other generated or generatable files please!) then you can `git add .`

After you do some work, check in the changes

```
git status
git commit -a -m "Descriptive comment about changes"
```

You can also make clones of the git repository in case you delete the directory.  Offsystem clones in case you delete the machine.

```
git clone ssh://hostname/path/to/repository
```

Comment: We use TortoiseSVN where I work. I'm not sure if it has the same capabilities as git that you mention, but I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: While I promote git over svn, either is so far in advanced of "tar" and "cp" to be indistinguishable.  The subversion commands will vary and you might need help getting a new repository set up for your project.